# why do my codes report error:'both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other '?

Tags: java, generics

The line `public <T> T putBean(T object) {` in the below code reports error: 'both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other'.
[image]
[image]

```
 @Override
public <T> T putBean(T object) {
    DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    BeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    beanDefinition.setBeanClassName(object.getClass().getName());
    beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(object.getClass().getName(),beanDefinition);
    return (T) object;
}
```

If I change `public <T> T putBean(T object) {` to `public <T> T putBean(Object object) {`, it does not report any error again. The new code is below:

```
 @Override
public <T> T putBean(Object object) {
    DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    BeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    beanDefinition.setBeanClassName(object.getClass().getName());
    beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(object.getClass().getName(),beanDefinition);
    return (T) object;
}
```

Why do the first code report the error 'both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other'? 
If I still want to use `public <T> T putBean(T object) {`, what should I do?

Comment: What is the method you are overriding here? Do NOT put images, instead add your sample code, a simplified version would do. Check this out for further clarifications: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Since the modified version works, it appears that you are overriding a method in the super class / interface with signature:

```
public <T> T putBean(Object object)
```

or perhaps:

```
public Object putBean(Object object)
```

so when you write in the subclass:

```
@Override
public <T> T putBean(T object)
```

You're specifying an incompatible signature, but because of type-erasure, the method actually becomes compatible internally, and the compiler is complaining about that conflict.

If you want to override the method, which the `@Override` annotation seems to indicate that you do, then the parameter must be `Object`.

If you didn't intend to override the method, then you need to give this new method a different name.

Comment: What does your 'signature' mean? Can you show me related article.

Comment: @shadowsocks https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html